# Android Application has stoppedd

Tags: java, android, react-native, android-studio

```
2020-08-24 13:52:48.722 8998-9031/com.mine**strong text**.organizer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-8-thread-1
Process: com.witech.organizer, PID: 8998
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field PREFER_LOCAL of type Lcom/google/android/gms/dynamite/DynamiteModule$VersionPolicy; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/dynamite/DynamiteModule; or its superclasses (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule' appears in /data/app/com.witech.organizer-Dea7k-xCNXDNlKsgiUGLCg==/base.apk:classes49.dex)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzx.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api@@17.3.0:52)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzaa.zza(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api@@17.3.0:12)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzx$zza.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-sdk-api@@17.3.0:11)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

I need to know how to fix this issue,
always quit "Application has stopped".
the application at the first time running good and stop again at the second time, and when I debug the problem, i got an error like the one above..

Thanks in advance.

**top level gradle file**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
 
buildscript {
    ext {
        googlePlayServicesVersion =  "+" // default: "+"
        firebaseMessagingVersion = "+" // default: "+"
 
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 24
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 29
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "16.0.1"
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
 
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
 
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
 
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
 
        maven {
            url "https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-maven-repository/raw/master/releases"
        }
 
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
 
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy {
                force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:$rootProject.ext.googlePlayServicesAuthVersion"
                force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:$rootProject.ext.googlePlayServicesAuthVersion"
                force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is probably not your fault, the error is coming from `Google Play SDK`. Could you post you gradle files?

Comment: also your app level gradle file

Comment: Try updating your libraries : `com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.4.0` and `com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.1.0`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while trying to use firebase in my project.

In my app/build.gradle dependencies i had

```
configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0"
        resolutionStrategy.force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1"
        resolutionStrategy.force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1"
        resolutionStrategy.force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0"
        resolutionStrategy.force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0"
    }
```

Upgrade all this libraries is working for me.
I get newest versions from https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases (search first occured "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads" and copy latest versions and made it for all play-services):

```
configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.3.0"
        resolutionStrategy.force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.3.0"
        resolutionStrategy.force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.3.0"
        resolutionStrategy.force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0"
        resolutionStrategy.force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0"
    }
```